# Как пригласить чужого бота, если он не публичный? Есть обходные пути?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

друзья. Хотелось бы узнать: есть ли варианты как пригласить чужого бота если он не публичный (пункт «PUBLIC BOT» отключен)? Понимаю, это встроенная функция Discord, и так очень сложно обходить, в отличии от плагинов и т.д, но очень интересный вопрос, кто знает — отпишите.[image: PUBLIC BOT]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете быть добавлены автором приложения в список тестировщиков приложения, после чего вы сами сможете пригласить бота на свой сервер.
Или человек, который создал бота, может дать вам ссылку для приглашения бота на сервер. Других способов нет